# Центрирование с помощью flexbox. Какой из этих вариантов лучше?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Для центрирования одновременно по горизонтали и вертикали встречаются два простых варианта.

Первый

```
.outer{
  display:flex;
}
.inner{
  margin:auto;
}
```

Второй

```
.outer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Результат вроде идентичный.

**Какой из этих способов лучше? В каких ситуациях и почему?**